# In Node JS, how can I redirect to a specific URL while outside of a route?

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, flash-message

I'd like to redirect to a specific URL and flash a message when an error occurs. However, in my error-handling file, I do not have access to the `res` variable that is inside routes. 
I tried performing HTTP requests to some route where I would queue the flash message and then call `res.redirect()` or `res.render()`, but the flash message never made it to the view.

So, how can I do the equivalent of a simple `res.redirect()` inside this other file?

Perhaps something like this in my error-handling file:

> `async function handler() {
>       await handle_error();
>           .then(fetch(someURL));
>   }`

and something else like this in my routes file:

> `router.get(someURL, function(req, res) {
>       req.flash('error', "An error has occurred");
>       res.redirect("/");
>   }`

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Please share your server code

Comment: @AmirHosseinRd added what I was attempting to do. Thank you

Comment: @Ramesh added what I was attempting to do. Thank you